# Network Coding Bittorrent library

Tags: bittorrent

I want to write a bittorrent library (or extented some of the exsisting like YAIRCC) to make it able to send and receive a file using network coding. To do this I need to send a message to peer about my linear combination of pieces. How can I do this? Do I have to use extension like LTEP or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What exactly does "using network coding" try to say? The straight-forward solution is to remote control an existing client using its API, like rTorrent via xmlrpc.

Comment: It means that I will code a file with network coding and send the linear combination to another users, the same with receiving.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using LTEP to advertise support for a new message, which when supported by both peers would be used instead of the standard REQUEST and PIECE message. That would be backwards compatible. Using network coding, your request message could be a lot simpler. You wouldn't have to specify which block you want for instance. It might still be useful to specify some information about some vectors that you would be especially interested in, to minimize linearly dependent blocks.

If you're looking for a bittorrent implementation to extend, you may want to take a look at [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org). It has a plugin interface for adding extension messages like these.

Now, I would think that whatever performance improvement you're hoping for will be entirely eaten up by reduction in disk performance. Keep in mind that solving the resulting equation system at the end of the download requires you to re-read (and probably write) every block several times to untangle their dependencies. This may cost you significant amount of time.

A more reasonable approach, in my mind, would be to limit the number of actual blocks any given block can be a combination of. That way, you trade off some of the redundancy benefits of network coding, but gain performance in resolving them at the end. In fact, it could be argued that the rarest-first algorithm works so well that any benefits network coding will bring you, will be insignificant.

Either way, I would recommend a simpler approach where you simply have XOR blocks only combining two other blocks. That way the requester would probably have to be explicit about which XOR block to download.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am using Network Coding, because it is my task, so I am not thinking if there will be any profits from it. How can I create a new type of message or content in LTEP? New dictionary?

Comment: Somewhat sparsely documented here http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/libtorrent_plugins.html see ut_metadata.cpp or smart_ban.cpp for examples